# Batch file doesn't work, how can I to fix it?

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a game using a batch script, but there is an error and I don't know what to do.

```
@echo on

goto log

:inicio

set "esquerda=caverna"
set "esquerda2=6"
set /p "run=Digite a acao: "
    if %run%==help (
goto help) else (
goto comands)


:carvena 

echo oi>"%userprofile%\desktop\oi.txt"
pause>nul

:comands 

echo %run% >"%tmp%\reino_de_merlock\personagem\comands.txt"
cd "%tmp%\reino_de_merlock\personagem"
type comands.txt | find /i "andar_esquerda" && echo andar>andar_esquerda.txt
if exist andar_esquerda.txt (
set "andar=esquerda1"
del /q andar_esquerda.txt
goto andar1)

:log

for /f %%a in ('type "%tmp%\reino_de_merlock\personagem\agilidade.txt"') do (
    set "agilidade=%%a" & goto inicio)

:andar1

if "%andar%" == "esquerda1" (
set /a andar = agilidade - esquerda2
if %andar% LEQ 0 (
goto %esquerda%)) 1>nul 2>nul
pause>nul
```

The error is in `set /a andar = agilidade - esquerda2`, the variable becomes esquerda1 and the right it's -2, what is the error?

Comment: No guy ! i love dos and i will never to stop to use him !!!

Comment: What's wrong with the variable becoming 2?

Comment: No, the variable become esquerda1 and the right was -2

Comment: @duskwuff: We don't do language wars here. Please stop. If you don't want to see questions about batch programming, ignore them or set a filter to not see them. It's not your choice what language is used or questions are asked about; it's the choice of the poster of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i only was doing jokes with him not a "language wars".

Comment: @KenWhite: While I understand your position, the fact of the matter is that MS-DOS batch scripts are a rather limited language (they were never intended to be used to write large programs!), and the author will undoubtedly encounter fundamental limitations of the interpreter in attempting to write an RPG using it. It's akin to a carpenter asking for help in building a house using an untied shoe to pound in nails — the correct answer is not "lace it up", but "use a hammer".

Comment: @duskwuff: Again, not your concern. :-) The fact is that the poster has asked a question about a problem in a batch script; I don't see anywhere it asks for an opinion on the choice of language being used. Comments are supposed to be to ask for information or clarify a point, not to reflect on the worth of the language the question concerns. There's even a hint in the empty comment area that reminds people of the use of comments.

Comment: Ok guy, sorry, but I don't know another language and I need some help in this, so i have to lace it up, i dont have a hammer.

Answer (score 1):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

In your case,

```
if %andar% LEQ 0 (
goto %esquerda%)
```

is contained within the block that starts

```
if "%andar%" == "esquerda1" (
```

and consequently uses the values of `andar` and `esquerda1` as they were when the `if "%andar%" == "esquerda1"` was reached, not on the new value of `andar` calculated **within** the loop.

Look for many SO entries on 'delayed expansion'